How do I change leaderstats from my other script?
I am making a tycoon game on Roblox. I have a dropper that drop parts when they come to the cube that destroys them they destroy, but now I want so when they touch this 'cube' the cash in leaderstats will change by 5.
Here is the code
local values = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Values

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Name == "DropperPart" and hit:IsA("BasePart") then
        values.Money.Value += hit:FindFirstChild("CashValue").Value
        hit:Destroy()
    end
end)


Many tycoons have some kind of "Owner" value that refers to the player that owns it. It is usually set when a player touches a button that claims it and starts the whole process. Could you find the code that add it to your question?
